# Fill in the Number Blanks

Tags: code-golf, number

You are given a list of 2-tuples of positive integers, of the form:

`a1 b1, a2 b2, ..., an bn`

In other words, the 2-tuples are comma-separated, and the integers within each tuple are space-separated. All of the `a` numbers are in strictly increasing order, as well as the `b`s. Your goal is to "fill in the gaps." What is meant by that is the following:

- If a<sub>i</sub>+1 == a<sub>i+1</sub>, don't do anything.
- Else if a<sub>i</sub>+1 < a<sub>i+1</sub>, you will insert tuples into the sequence as follows: a<sub>i</sub> b<sub>i</sub>, a<sub>i</sub>+1 b<sub>i+1</sub>, a<sub>i</sub>+2 b<sub>i+1</sub>, ..., a<sub>i+1</sub>-1 b<sub>i+1</sub>, a<sub>i+1</sub> b<sub>i+1</sub>.

In other words, if there is a "gap" in the a<sub>i</sub>, then you will insert more into the list with the inserted `b`s to be b<sub>i+1</sub> (the end of the gap).

**Example**:

Input: `6 125, 7 170, 10 185`

Output: `6 125, 7 170, 8 185, 9 185, 10 185`

**Scoring**: the score of the submission is the number of bytes needed to construct a program to, when given a string as described above, output in the same format the "filled" list of tuples.

Lowest score wins!

Comment: Can we assume that there will be at least two tuples?

Comment: @Dennis yes you can.

Comment: So in general for input of three tuples `a1 b1, a2 b2, a3 b3` the only pair that triggers an insert is `a1 b1, a3 b3` requiring an insert of `a2 b3`, but where should it be inserted?

Comment: My interpretation is that a counts from a(min) to a(max) and outputs b for the next highest-or-equal value of a.  So because there's no a=8 and a=9, those both use the b value for a=10.

Comment: does the output have to be in that same format with space separation and no brackets?

Comment: and does it have to be comma-space separated or is comma separated okay

Comment: @PeterTaylor It should be inserted to keep the sorted ordering of the `a`s.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food That's correct.

Comment: @Maltysen It has to be in the same format as given above.

Comment: I tried to edit a bit to make it clear. Rollback if that is not what you meant.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Thank you! I didn't know how to do it without LaTeX (why is it not supported?).

Comment: @Ryan [It was disabled because of bugs.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5056/25180)

Comment: @jimmy23013 That's unfortunate!

Comment: @ophact These seem totally unrelated to me

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms this was discussed in TNB, it was agreed that this question would be closed as a duplicate of the new one because the new one is "more usable and better specified". They are related because they both involve filling in gaps with the next seen number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
Jsrz7Pjds,R+ehfghTdcJ2\,}hJePJ
```

*1 byte thanks to Jakube.*

At the high level, for each number in the range of the a's, the list is filtered for a's greater than that number, then the b from the first such tuple is used as the b.

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Jsrz7Pjds%2CR%2BehfghTdcJ2%5C%2C%7DhJePJ&input=6+125%2C+7+170%2C+10+185&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>42</s> <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
q~,]:T(\-2=),>{IST2/z~\{I<!}#=,',S}fI&
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%2C%5D%3AT(%5C-2%3D)%2C%3E%7BIST2%2Fz~%5C%7BI%3C!%7D%23%3D%2C'%2CS%7DfI%26&input=6%20125%2C%207%20170%2C%2010%20185).

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>192</s> <s>180</s> 171 Bytes

Unfortunately, it takes a *ton* of bytes to parse the input and format output. Also, thanks to Sp3000 for kicking my brain into gear :)

```py
n=[map(int,x.split())for x in input().split(',')]
for i in range(len(n)-1):j=0;exec'print n[i][0]+j,`n[i+(j>0)][1]`+",",;j+=1;'*(n[i+1][0]-n[i][0])
print n[-1][0],n[-1][1]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.5.0b1](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350b1/)+, 123 bytes

```py
L=map(eval,(input()+",").split())
o=""
while L:
 *L,a,b=L;x=a-1
 while[x,b,*L][-2]<a:o=", %d %d"%(a,*b)+o;a-=1
print(o[2:])
```

Parsing the input was a pain, so I just ignored it and parsed it as is. This means that

```
6 125, 7 170, 10 185
```

gets parsed as

```
[6, (125,), 7, (170,), 10, (185,)]
```

hence the splat in the string formatting.

Comment: Why so specific as to the version?

Comment: @BetaDecay Probably relies on features introduced in the 3.5.0 beta 1 that were absent in previous releases.

Comment: @BetaDecay What Alex said, specifically [PEP448 - Additional Unpacking Generalisations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). Otherwise, instead of `(a,*b)` I'd have to do `((a,)+b)` or `(a,b[0])`. Older versions of Python would give a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (*ES6*), 97 <s>103</s>

Finding the question wording hard to understand, I based my work on the example.

<s>First try, there could be a shorter way with just 1 split</s> Scanning the input string in a single pass using replace.

```js
f=l=>
  l.replace(/\d+/g,b=>{
    for(i=p||a-1;a&&i++<a;p=a)o+=`, ${i} `+b;
    a=a?0:b
  },p=a=o='')
&&o.slice(2)

// TEST

out=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

test=v=>out(v+'\n->'+f(v))

test('6 125, 7 170, 10 185')
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
<input id=I><button onclick='test(I.value)'>-></button>
```

.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 152 bytes

```
p(x,y)=", "++show x++' ':show y
(a:b:c)%x|a<x=c%x|0<1=(x,b)
g a=p.(a%)=<<[0+head a..last$init a]
main=interact$drop 2.g.(map(read.fst).lex=<<).words
```

#### How it works

`p` is a simple string formatting helper function:

```
>>> p (6, 125)
", 6 125"
```

`(%)` is a "lookup" function for filling in blanks:

```
>>> let nums = [6, 125, 7, 135, 10, 185]
>>> nums % 8
(8,185)
```

`[head a..last$init a]` is the range of numbers to use: from the first integer parsed until the second-to-last integer parsed. (The `0+` helps the type-checker infer that the whole program deals with `Num` values; otherwise `read` doesn't know what to parse.) Then we `concatMap` (or `=<<`) our previous functions over the range to get one big string. That's what `g` does:

```
>>> g nums
", 6 125, 7 135, 8 185, 9 185, 10 185"
```

Finally, there's `main`. It's of the form `interact$s`, so all we care about is the function `s :: String -> String` that turns *stdin* into *stdout*.

First, to read input, we split into words:

```
>>> (words) "6 125, 7 170, 10 185"
["6","125,","7","170,","10","185"]
```

Then we `concatMap` the function `map(read.fst).lex` over this list. For one word, this does:

```
>>> (map(read.fst).lex) "125," :: [Int]
[125]
```

So for a list of words, you get `concat [[6], [125], [7], ...] == [6, 125, 7...]`, which is the list we want to pass to `g`. Finally, we `drop` the leading `", "` from the string `g` gives us.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 34 bytes

```
ri_[_q~,]:,2/::fe&:.e|+ee>Sf*", "*
```

I started with golfing [Dennis's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53028/25180) but finally it becomes nothing like the original.

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri_%5B_q%7E%2C%5D%3A%2C2%2F%3A%3Afe%26%3A.e%7C%2Bee%3ESf*%22%2C%20%22*&input=6%20125%2C%207%20170%2C%2010%20185)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 67 bytes

(66 characters code + 1 character command line option)

```
s/(\b\d+ \d+)(?=, (?!(??{$k=$1+1}) ).+( \d+))/"$1, ".$k.$2/e&&redo
```

Execution example:

```
perl -pe 's/(\b\d+ \d+)(?=, (?!(??{$k=$1+1}) ).+( \d+))/"$1, ".$k.$2/e&&redo' <<< "6 125, 7 170, 10 185"
```

**Explanation:**
General approach is to construct a regex which is capable of looking ahead to the next token to determine if it increases by one (regex is rubbish at arithmetic, so we add a perl execution to do the addition, then look for that). If it does not, we replace this match with the original text, plus the new token with the increased index. We then repeat this multiple times on the input until it does not change.

For the below explanation, a 'section' is the comma separated value, and the 'tokens' are the space separated values within this.

```
 s/     
   (\b\d+ \d+)             # Matches the first two numbers in a section
   (?=,                 # Look ahead to the next section
     (?!(??{$k=$1+1}) ) # Make sure the first token in the next section is not increased by one, store this value in $k. Happily, although our $1 contains TWO space separated numbers, it increases the first number and ignores the second - strange behaviour in Perl.
     .+                 # Ignore the actual value of first token of the next section (i.e. the index)
     ( \d+)             # Create a backreference on the second (i.e. the value)
   )   
 /                      # Start the replacement string...
   "$1, "               # Put the first section back into the result
   .$k                  # Append the increased index
   .$2                  # Append the value of the next token
 /e                     # Modifier - allows us to execute Perl inside the RegEx
 &&redo              # Repeat until it no longer changes the string
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 174 bytes

Indented for clarity:

```
class P{
    static void Main(string[]z){
        int a=0,b,i=-1;
        while(++i<z.Length){
            b=int.Parse(z[i++]);
            while(a<b)
                System.Console.Write((a==0?"":", ")+(a+=a==0?b:1)+" "+z[i].Trim(','));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 232 bytes

Not really *that* short, but it uses a different method to the Python solution already posted

```python
l=list(map(int,[y for x in input().split(',')for y in x.split(' ')]))
f=[];x=1
while x:
 x=0
 for i in range(0,len(l)-2,2):
  if l[i+2]-l[i]>1:l[:i+2]+=l[i]+1,;l[:i+3]+=l[i+4],;x+=1
for n in range(len(l)):print(l[n],end=','if n%2 else' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + coreutils, 87

```
tr , \\n|while read a b
do for((p=p?p:a-1;p++<a;c=1)){
echo -n ${c+, }$p $b
}
p=$a
done
```

#### Test output:

```
$ echo "6 125, 7 170, 10 185" | ./fillblanks.sh 
6 125, 7 170, 8 185, 9 185, 10 185
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 229 bytes

I *think* I've whittled this down as much as I can. I would be interested to see if there is a better approach that leads to a shorter Java answer:

```
String f(String s){String r="",g=" ",x[]=s.split(",\\s"),z[];int i=0,p=0,l=x.length,a,b;while(i<l){z=x[i].split(g);a=new Integer(z[0]);b=new Integer(z[1]);if(i++>0)while(a>++p)r+=p+g+b+", ";r+=a+g+b+(i==l?"":", ");p=a;}return r;}
```

Formatted:

```
String f(String s) {
    String r = "", g = " ", x[] = s.split(",\\s"), z[];
    int i = 0, p = 0, l = x.length, a, b;
    while (i < l) {
        z = x[i].split(g);
        a = new Integer(z[0]);
        b = new Integer(z[1]);
        if (i++ > 0)
            while (a > ++p)
                r += p + g + b + ", ";
        r += a + g + b + (i == l ? "" : ", ");
        p = a;
    }
    return r;
}
```